# How to create Custom Tournament Bracket widget

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi everyone i'm trying to create a "flowchart" like final stage table football using flutter but i don't know which widget i should use for that. Here is what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "final stage table football"-`Widget` in Flutter. However, Flutter is great for creating your own widgets.

If you are completely new to Flutter, you should probably start [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro).

If you already know how to interact with widgets, then you might want to take a look at the [`CustomPainter` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html), which is the *most basic* way to draw custom shapes, like the lines in your screenshot.

As you might want to compose `Container`s (with the necessary text children) for your boxes together with these lines, you could combine them using a `Stack` widget.

Comment: Hi, did you got it ? @creativecreatorormaybenot